# how the continue statement works in for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I have the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while(i)
    {
        int index = 0;
        printf("while begin\n");

        for(index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        {
            if(index == 2)
            {
                continue;    
            }
            printf("within for\n");
        }
        printf("while end\n");
    }

    printf("returned from while");
}
```

does the `continue` effect the `for loop` or the `while loop` directly? looks like once the `continue` is called, `for loop` will start to run from the beginning, should not the `while loop` start to run from the beginning?

Comment: It affects the nearest loop in whose body it is written. Only for loop will be affected, while loop will not be affected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continue` will cause the remaining portion of the enclosing `for` or `while` loop body to be skipped. In your case, the `for` is the "enclosing" loop of `continue` and the while loop is the "enclosing" scope of the `for` loop.

According to (unofficial) [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue)

> The continue statement causes a jump, as if by goto to the end of the
>   loop body (it may only appear within the loop body of for, range-for,
>   while, and do-while loops).

Answer (score 1):

To understand what continue is you should know what break does too.

So the following peace of code shows you how break and continue works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int hours = 10;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<hours;i++){
        if(i==5){
            break;
        }

        printf("%d ",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 0 1 2 3 4

As you can see, when i reaches 5 (i==5) the loop breaks.

Now let's take a look of what does continue if we replace break using the same code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int hours = 10;
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<hours;i++){
        if(i==5){
            continue;
        }

        printf("%d ",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9

As you can see it doesn't leave the loop (like when using break), instead when **i** reach 5 (i==5) ignore the rest of the body making the loop to start over from the point where **i** was last time seen.
The number **5** *is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to think about it is to say : "it goes back to the top of the loop" anything AFTER the *continue* won't be processed.

Comment: You should be clear when you say _anything after_ `continue` .

Comment: Thanks for the request, I mean when your program reaches the statement [continue] it returns to the top of the current loop and it does not process whatever is after the [continue] , it is a very practical way to process information and I use it a lot.