# Could I get clarification on the continue statement?

Tags: c, continue

I want clarification on the `continue` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int i;

    while (i < 10) {
        if (i == 4) {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs 0-9, skipping the number 4. I removed the increment statement below `if` statement:

```
 while (i < 10) {
        if (i == 4) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
```

I read `continue` will break one iteration of the loop. I assumed it will continue to the `printf` statement, move on and still output 0-9, skipping 4.

It is stuck in a loop and only printed 0, 1, 2 & 3.

Comment: You need to initialize your variable i = 0.  It currently is unitialized.

Comment: i will always be 4 since you're not incrementing it before the continue. Infinite loop.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks. Wouldn't the increment after the printf statement do the work? Thank you!

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166912/how-the-continue-statement-works-in-for-loop-in-c . 
- Please do not create new questions with same queries. 
- Research more first and then raise only if you were unable to find any viable solution.

Comment: "It does not process, as I assumed, whatever it is after the continue statement." I can't understand this expectation. Code runs in the order it's written, unless something explicitly changes that. So... you were expecting `continue` to... do nothing at all?

Comment: No... It never gets called because of the continue.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to make it a bit clearer:

```c
int main (void) {
    int i = 0; // you need to initialize `i` before reading from it

    while (i < 10) {
        if (i == 4) {
            i++;       // here you change the value
            continue;  // ok, go directly to the next lap in the while loop
        }
        // here i is: 0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
        i++;        
    }
}
```

and here's your second version:

```c
int main (void) {
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 10) {   // <---------+
                       //           |
        if (i == 4) {  // if 4, ----+
            continue;  // when `i` reaches 4, when will `i++` be reached?
        }              // hint: never

        i++;           // 0=>1, 1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>4 ... never to be reached anymore
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`continue` would end and start the next iteration of **the CLOSEST** loop **only**. The *closest* here means the current loop.

Notes:

- `if` is not a loop.
- `for`, `while` are loops.